# How to prevent any changes on table between two different queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So lets say I have a couple of processes in my rails application that can all access the DB. Now in one of the processes I want to query a table and stright afterwards to query it again. My question is how can I make sure no edits were made to the table by other processes between the two queries made by the same process? Will transaction help here? I dont think so.

Comment: `A transaction acts on a single database connection. If you have multiple class-specific databases, the transaction will not protect interaction among them. One workaround is to begin a transaction on each class whose models you alter:`

Comment: What behaviour do you want if another session tries to modify the data between these two queries? Throw an error? Or do you just want to know if the data has changed so you can re-query it and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you have a few options. I don't know a lot about your app's architecture or what database you are using. Depending on what database you are using (mysql, pgsql, etc) you have the ability to do [table locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html). The details of how this work differ from significantly DB to DB. Other than locking the table you could use some kind of queuing system (lick [active job](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html), or [delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)) that will queue all the writes to that table and only processes writes to that table once the current write is complete. This is a real high level explanation and there are some considerations that you need to take into account such as:

- Does the user or system expect these writes to be real time
- Will delaying these writes cause a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)
- Do you have the resources to integrate a queuing system
- Does your current database offer table locking

So these are some starting point for your research I will say that if you are just going to stop table edits you are going to have to ensure that you store all the writes that would have occurred white the table is in a locked state.